# Excel: Stop arrow keys generating cell references in cell selection boxes

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I'm writing a Conditional Format function, such as this one:

```
=AND($R1<>"",$S1="",$T1="",$U1="")
```

I want to add `TRIM()` to each cell reference, but when I put the cursor at `=` and then attempt to use the arrow keys to move through the text Excel thinks I'm trying to use the arrow keys to select cells and throws cell references into my formula. Is there a way to have Excel **not** do this, and just move through the text as normal, so I can edit it as I would in notepad.

Obviously there is a work-around of pasting the formula to notepad and back again, and there may be better ways to look for populated and non populated data.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to that:(

Comment: Try manage rules, edit rule and double click in the formula then press F2 and use the arrow normally

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a rule, you can use F2 to get into edit mode in most such boxes, even when you're not explicitly prompted to use it. That includes in Conditional Formatting dialogues, the Name Manager for Named Ranges, entering formulae, etc.

Comment: Is this working for anyone on Excel for Mac? F2 does work in regular spreadsheet cells, but not in the conditional formatting range editor.

Comment: Excel for Windows does this as well, and it's incredibly disruptive and time wasting.